# How to let typescript skip or exclude not used files

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm wondering if it's possible to let typescript not check files that are not imported.
I'm experimenting with a mono repo where multiple projects get a copy of a shared folder.
That shared folder is copied into the `src` folder as `src/shared` some files in the share folder are used by projectX some are not. Those may be used by projectY.

Is it possible to let typescript not check for example `src/shared/components/AvatarMenu.vue` since it's not imported. Because that file uses a dependency let's say `dayjs` that projectX doens't have, and doesnt need.

So it will prevent from this error to be thrown:

```
4 import dayjs from "@/application/plugins/dayjs";
```

Comment: tsconfig `exclude: [src/shared]`? Tho I don't thing a shared folder in monorepo is better then a shared *acpackage*